# Viewstate verification failed. Reason: The viewstate supplied failed integrity check. 2

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have been getting the error message that Viewstate verification failed. Reason: The viewstate supplied failed integrity check.  and data is unable to be saved using my website until I recycle IIS. I read that this has something to do with a machine key within a server farm. I am not sure? This is just a stand alone webserver. Any ideas how to correct this?

```
Event code: 4009  Event message: Viewstate verification failed. Reason: The viewstate supplied failed integrity check.  Event time: 8/26/2013 3:30:58 PM  Event time (UTC): 8/26/2013 7:30:58 PM  Event ID: 6edb892ff6194dc48ef1182cee318e63  Event sequence: 4  Event occurrence: 1  Event detail code: 50203    Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130220190575673097 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\website\ 
    Machine name:    Process information: 
    Process ID: 3636 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: Domain\account   Request information: 
    Request URL: 
    Request path: /frmFoodAndBeverage.aspx 
    User host address:
    User: 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Negotiate 
    Thread account name: Domain\account   ViewStateException information: 
    Exception message: Invalid viewstate. 
    Client IP: 
    Port: 
    User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0) 
    PersistedState: /wEPDwUKLTYzODM0NTY2Mg9kFgJmD2QWAgIDD2QWAgIDDw8WAh4EVGV4dAUPQmVsbCwgRG9uYWxkIEUuZGQYAQUeX19Db250cm9sc1JlcXVpcmVQb3N0QmFja0tleV9fFgEFIWN0bDAwJENvbnRlbnRQbGFjZUhvbGRlcjEkY21kTmV4dF5K3yklWc0DODJ8SLoJw+dFVUlgm/CktMaD1teAlLBl

    Referer: 
    Path: /frmFoodAndBeverage.aspx    Custom event details:
```

Comment: Have you see this: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;829743

Comment: Do you think setting enableViewStateMac="false" will fix it?

Comment: I am using alot of session variables in my code could this be why

Comment: Try disabling mac check, and see what happen. However, you should keep your variables at server side in Session instead of in Viewstate, where you are charging your page with a lot of data and making it slow to load..

Comment: I dont know where this machine.config file is?

Comment: No, don't do it in machine.config! It will change the behavior of all web applications in your machine! Instead change it in web.config, to modify only the current application.
<system.web>
  <pages enableViewStateMac="false" />
</system.web>
Be aware, disabling this check is a really bad practice!

Comment: Ok why is this bad practice? What am I opening up?

Comment: Do yo go out and leave the door open?
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/11/web-farms-and-aspnet-viewstate.html

Comment: Thanks, I dont understand why I get this error like twice a day and I dont run multiple servers just one???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check if the problem is into the machine authentication code(MAC). Set  enableViewStateMac="false". If you no longer get view state errors, the problem is related to the MAC feature.
Also you can generate a new machineKey and copy it into the web.config of your app on each server. Here are some links that might help...
explanation of machineKey
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9.aspx
machineKey generator
http://www.codeproject.com/aspnet/machineKey.asp

Comment: It says to do this in the machine.config file? Where is that?

Comment: I only have one server

Comment: This is a Page property: 
`<asp:Page EnableViewStateMac="True|False" />`

Comment: x:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[version]\config\machine.config

Comment: *Don't leave the enableViewStateMac option disabled* -- just use it as a troubleshooting step.  Probably the real solution is to specify the machine key.